# How to include framework setup package, in App package , in Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm new in Cocoa. My Application require to use third-party framework to be able to launch. How can I integrate that framework setup, in my Application package (using PackageMaker) , so it will be installed automatically if it needed.

Like in Visual Studio, when you make Setup project, you have option to include other frameworks, libraries, to be installed automatically with your App if it's needed.

P.S. I was told to include that framework in my App, using Xcode. I tried, but I think I missed something. [Integrate open-source framework into my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7937964/integrate-open-source-framework-into-my-app)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Theres no need to add it in package maker. If your app requires the use of a 3rd party framework you can add it in Xcode under frameworks. Then go and add a build phase "copy files" to frameworks and add your framework.

Comment: Thanks, so it means, other users can run that App, without installing it?

Comment: Exactly, as long as the framework is copied into your applications frameworks folder it will work fine.